# Why list elements after space disappear when passed from views to Django template?

Tags: html, django

I use Django 2.1. I have some code in views.py:

**views.py**

```
...
zipped = zip(ph, mean)
return render(request,'project/list.html',
                {'section': 'project', 'lines': zipped})
```

so far everything is correct, I debugged and all works.

**Data**

```
ph = ['Pre formation', 'Nice view'] #as an example not exact values
mean = [10.0, 14.6]
```

However inside html

**html**

```
{% for ph, mean in lines %}
...
<td><input type="text" size="35" name="txt1" value={{ph}}></td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" name="txt2" value={{mean}}></td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

**Data I get**

```
Pre 10.0
Nice 14.6
```

**Question**:
Why does it take only the text till space inside html? Inside views I debugged zipped has all information.
How can I fix it?

Comment: You need quotes around your value: `value="{{ph}}"`

Comment: Inspecting the resulting HTML in your browser and checking the HTML spec wiould have answered your question...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was because of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for ph, mean in lines %}
...
<td><input type="text" size="35" name="txt1" value="{{ph}}"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" name="txt2" value="{{mean}}"></td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Quotes around value are missing.